# Form submit in continuous loop?

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

This is my view: **product_information.php**

```
<form id="form-product-info" data-parsley-validate class="form-horizontal form-label-left">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="product-SKU">SKU <span class="required">*</span>
              </label>
              <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <input type="text" id="product-SKU" required="required" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" value="<?php echo $results[0]->SKU; ?>">
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="ln_solid"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-3">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="btn-customer-list">Cancel</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" id="btn-delete-product">Delete</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success source">Submit</button>
              </div>
            </div>

          </form>
```

This is my controller: **product.php**

```
public function updateProductInformation()
    {
        $product_information['name'] = $this->input->post('name');
        $product_information['SKU'] = $this->input->post('SKU'); 
        $product_information['product_id'] = $this->input->post('id');

        $product_information['last_updated'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

        var_dump($product_information);
        $update = $this->updateProductInformation($product_information);

        $this->update($update);
    }
```

The JavaScript file: **product.js**

```
$('#form-product-info').submit(function() {
  alert('Submitting form');
  var id = $('#product-name').data('product-id');
  updateProductInformation(id);
});

function updateProductInformation(id)
{
  alert('Updating product information ' + id);
  var name  = $('#product-name').val();
  var SKU = $('#product-SKU').val();
  alert(name);
  alert(SKU);
  alert(id);  

  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: base_url + 'product/updateProductInformation',
    data: {
      'name' : name,
      'SKU' : SKU,
      'id' : id
    },
    success: function(msg)
    {
      if (msg == 'true')
      {
        alert('Updating product information successful');
      }
      else
      {
        alert("Please try again. ");
      }
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
      console.log('Response text: ' + jqXHR.responseText);
      console.log('Status code: ' + textStatus);
      console.log('Error thrown: ' + errorThrown);
    }
  });
}
```

When I hit submit, an error is thrown in the console. When I open it in a new tab, I get a continuous stream of this:

```
array(4) { ["name"]=> NULL ["SKU"]=> NULL ["product_id"]=> NULL ["last_updated"]=> string(19) "2017-09-23 10:07:20" }
```

Until eventually it runs out of memory and I get a fatal error. I can't seem to find what could be causing this. The alerts I set show only once as they should. The **updateProductInformation(id)** is assigned to only one event handler as far as I have checked. And even if it was being called from other places, then the alerts should be showing more than once.

Comment: where is the  `product-name` selector?

Comment: try this `$('.source').attr('disabled','disabled');` after `alert('Submitting form');` and `$('.source').removeAttr('disabled');` in ajax `success` or `error` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the culprit:

```
 $update = $this->updateProductInformation($product_information);
```

This should be:

```
$update = $this->Product_model->updateProductInformation($product_information);
```

Can be quite easy to miss!